# Dealloc called twice and crash at [super dealloc]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, nstimer

---- question solved by myself, info updated in my comment ----

I have a view controller which has a periodic NSTimer. I call invalidate of the timer When I remove the view controller:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc called");
    if ([myTimer isValid]) {
        [myTimer invalidate];
    }
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I discovered an unexpected behavior that the [myTimer invalidate] will immediately call my view controller's dealloc. That's why I put the isValid check to avoid crash. But the [super dealloc] will be called twice and crash the app.

Thus, I have two questions:

1. What's the proper way to invalidate a timer?
2. Why is the timer's invalidate method call the view controller's dealloc method?

Thanks

Leo

Comment: You should put invalidate statement under viewDidUnload to avoid crash.

Comment: That sounds like some odd behaviour. Are there any other objects holding on to a reference to your view controller - if not, is there any possibility that once the timer is removed & released from `NSRunLoop` the view controller has nothing referencing it anymore (and so is deallocated)?

Comment: @studev, you are right. I just figured the view controller was incorrectly released out side this code. The timer's invalidate will release the target but the target's dealloc was not supposed to be call. Rather the retain count should decrease from 2 to 1.  Since when I schedule the timer, the timer retained the target.

Comment: Ok good to hear - I'll add my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like some odd behaviour. Are there any other objects holding on to a reference to your view controller?

If not, there is a possibility that once the timer is removed & released from the run loop the view controller has nothing referencing it anymore (and so is deallocated).

Answer (score 3):

As described at [CocoaDev: NSTimer](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTimer):

> Here are a couple of rules that might help you with NSTimer:
>
> A timer retains the target and userInfo objects.
>
> A timer is automatically retained by the run loop when scheduling it.
>
> If a timer is not set to repeat, it will automatically invalidate itself upon firing.
>
> A timer is released from the run loop when calling invalidate.
>
> A timer releases the target and userInfo objects when calling invalidate.
>
> In other words, if you release a repeating timer without invalidating it, it will continue to repeate because the run loop is retaining it. However, if you don't want to stop the timer before the application quits, or if the timer is non-repeating, you can release it after scheduling it without calling invalidate.

Comment: If you copy and paste contents that you haven’t written yourself, please cite the original source and make it clear that the text is not yours. Plagiarism is frowned upon and may be considered illegal.

Comment: sorry .... I had no idea this is how it is done.. I am a new member.. :) will keep that in mind.